# How Key and value Iterate in Vue Js

Tags: loops, vue.js, for-loop, vue-component, v-for

I'm trying to iterate bellow array with key and value in vue.js.

```
attributes = {"Size - UK":"12","Color":"White"}.
```

this `array` is getting from database as `string`

I want result as below

`Size : 12 Color : White`

I used below method to do that

```
 <span :v-for="(item, index) in attributes">
     {{item}} : {{index}}
 </span>
```

and I got an error like this.

`Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-for` attribute should not have `:` (see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html))

Try this with `:` removed:

```js
// https://codepen.io/collection/naevzw/
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items:
      { message: 'Foo', text: 'Bar', other: 'FooBar' }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- v-for - VUE.js Guide Example -->
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="(key) in Object.keys(items)">
    {{ key }} : {{ items[key] }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried it. but I'm getting result as this way '0 : { 1 : " 2 : S 3 : i 4 : z 5 : e 6 : 7 : - 8 : 9 : U 10 : K 11 : " 12 : : 13 : " 14 : 1 15 : 2 16 : " 17 : , 18 : " 19 : C 20 : o 21 : l 22 : o 23 : r 24 : " 25 : : 26 : " 27 : W 28 : h 29 : i 30 : t 31 : e 32 : " 33 : } '

Comment: I getting this array from database as `string`, is this a issue ?

Comment: Problem is my array is string I add `JSON.parse(items)` to.problem is fixed. Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span v-for="key in Object.keys(attributes)">
     {{key}} : {{attributes[key]}}
 </span>
```

Comment: This is not working. Getting Error called `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'undefined' in {"Size - UK":"12","Color":"White"}`

Comment: I tried it. but I'm getting result as this way '0 : { 1 : " 2 : S 3 : i 4 : z 5 : e 6 : 7 : - 8 : 9 : U 10 : K 11 : " 12 : : 13 : " 14 : 1 15 : 2 16 : " 17 : , 18 : " 19 : C 20 : o 21 : l 22 : o 23 : r 24 : " 25 : : 26 : " 27 : W 28 : h 29 : i 30 : t 31 : e 32 : " 33 : } '

Comment: Problem is my array is string I add `JSON.parse(attributes)` to.problem is fixed. Thanks All